# How do I access Rails fixtures from javascript unit tests?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, teaspoon

We have done a lot of work testing on the rails side of our application now and are starting to try out unit testing on the javascript side using Teaspoon/Mocha/Sinon/Expectjs.

Now that we are digging deeper we are trying to find the *right* way to access rails fixture data. For example we want to be able to make a correct api call to (mocked) server with an `ActiveRecord` model's `id` number (to call, e.g., `/users/:some_id`), but these are generated at runtime by the fixture generation.

So far the only way we've gotten this to work is to create a `MagicLamp` fixture which renders json (instead of, say, a rails partial) and then to call `MagicLamp.loadJSON()` instead of `MagicLamp.load`. However this seems like a hacky way to achieve this. Essentially we hoped there'd be a way to have a file like `magic_lamp.rb` where you can just set up a function similar to the fixture helpers that Rails generates (e.g., `users(:name_of_user)` for a `users.yml` file).

I'll admit I may be asking the wrong question here, because it seems like this should be trivial. Maybe we're on the wrong path?